# Proving that $\int_0^l (\cos \beta_nx-\frac2{\beta_nl}\sin \beta_nx)(\cos \beta_mx-\frac2{\beta_ml}\sin \beta_mx)dx=0$

Tags: real-analysis, integration

We have known that $\beta_nl\sin (\beta_nl)=2(1-\cos (\beta_nl))$ and $sin (\beta_nl)=\frac12\beta_nl(1+\cos (\beta_nl))$.

Consider natural number m, n which satisfied above condition (m≠n)

Proved that $\int_0^l (\cos \beta_nx-\frac2{\beta_nl}\sin \beta_nx)(\cos \beta_mx-\frac2{\beta_ml}\sin \beta_mx)dx=0$

This is a very small part of the complex problem in my excercise, I have tried integrated directly and simplified the formula with above condition. However, I can only get the sum of the last three term was zero. In other words, I could not find a way to prove $\int_0^l \cos \beta_nx\cos \beta_mxdx=0$. Does somebody know how to prove the property?

Thanks a lot!!

**EDIT:**
This is my work so far. A little complicated. $\delta_{nm}$ represents the integral after direct integration.
[image]

Comment: When you write for example $\cos \beta_nl$, does it mean $\cos(\beta_nl)$ or $\cos(\beta_n) l$ ? Same ambiguity for  $\cos \beta_n x$, If it is the first option, I think you would have a simpler presentation by setting $\gamma_n=\beta_n l$ etc.

Comment: the first option, sorry for the misleading presentation

Comment: Similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1403579/305862) with the nice Sturm-Liouville explanation in the answer by @mickep

Answer (score 0):

Preliminary commentary :

If your initial constraints are written under the form :

$$\begin{cases}a \sin a=2(1-\cos a)\\ \sin a=\frac12a(1+\cos a)\end{cases}$$

Using classical trigonometric formulas, this system boils down to

$$\begin{cases}\frac{a}{2}\cos \frac{a}{2} = \sin \frac{a}{2} \iff \tan b = b\\ \sin \frac{a}{2}=\frac{a}{2} \cos \frac{a}{2} \iff \tan b = b\end{cases}$$

with $b=\frac{a}{2}=\frac12\beta_n \ell$.

So, your two first equations contain the same information, i.e. that the

$$r_n:=\frac12\beta_n l$$

are the roots of equation $$\tan x = x$$ which has an infinite number of solutions (with $x_n\approx (2n+1)\pi/2$ for large $n$ : draw a graphical representation...).

which amounts to say that :

$$\begin{cases} \cos(\frac12\beta_n \ell)-\frac{2}{\beta_n \ell}\sin(\frac12\beta_n \ell)&=&0\\
\cos(\frac12\beta_m \ell)-\frac{2}{\beta_m \ell}\sin(\frac12\beta_m \ell)&=&0
\end{cases}$$

Let us now prove that :

$$I_{mn}:=\int_0^{\color{red}{\ell/2}} \underbrace{(\cos \beta_nx-\frac2{\beta_nl}\sin \beta_nx)}_{e_n(x)}\underbrace{(\cos \beta_mx-\frac2{\beta_ml}\sin \beta_mx)}_{e_m(x)}dx=0$$

[take care to the $\color{red}{\ell/2}$ !]

Please note that

$$e''_m(x)=-(\beta_m)^2e_m(x) \ \text{and} \ e''_n(x)=-(\beta_n)^2e_n(x)$$

A classical technique in such questions is **double integration by parts** formula :

$$\int_a^{b} u v'' dx =  \int_a^{b} u'' v dx + \begin{cases}+ u(b) v'(b) \\- u(a) v'(a)\\ - u'(b) v(b) \\ + u'(a) v(a)\end{cases}$$

Let us take in the previous formula

$u(x)=e_n(x), \ \ v(x)=e_m(x), \ \ with \ \ a=0,b=\ell/2,$

we obtain the following expression (in which *** are for unimportant factors)

$$\int_0^{\ell/2} e_n e''_m dx =  \int_0^{\ell/2} e''_n e_m dx +\begin{cases} + \underbrace{(\cos(\frac12\beta_n \ell)-\frac{2}{\beta_n \ell}\sin(\frac12\beta_n \ell))}_{= 0} \ \times \ (***) \\
- (-2/\ell) \\
+ (***) \ \times \ \underbrace{(\cos(\frac12\beta_m \ell)-\frac{2}{\beta_m \ell}\sin(\frac12\beta_m \ell))}_{= 0}\\
-2/\ell
\end{cases}$$

The previous identity can be written :

$$\underbrace{\int_0^{\ell/2} e_n (-\beta_m^2)e_m dx} =  \int_0^{\ell/2} (-\beta_n^2)e_n e_m dx + 0$$

As $\beta_n \ne \beta_m$, this  proves that

$$\int_0^{\ell/2} e_n e_m dx = 0$$

---

Important remark : This issue can be turned, in the setting of **Sturm-Liouville theory**, into an eigenvalues/eigenfunctions problem where the $r_n$s (as defined above) are eigenvalues of a certain self-adjoint operator associated with a system of **orthogonal** eigenfunctions, the $e_n$s, which is a natural way to interprete your integral equal to zero.

("self-adjoint" qualificative refers naturaly to the property $\int u''v=\int uv''$ we have obtained above).

Comment: Are you familiar with the Sturm-Liouville theory ? A first reference of the connection with your issue can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3156624/305862)

Comment: So far, I tried to calculate the integral directly and used the second condition to simplify my formula.

Comment: [Here](https://people.uncw.edu/hermanr/mat463/ODEBook/Book/SL.pdf) is a good tutorial on Sturm-Liouville theory.

Comment: Another similar problem [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4222470/305862).

Comment: Sorry, I am studying the theory, because I have not learned it before.

Comment: I have just proven your identity but in the case where the upper bound is $\ell/2$ instead of $\ell$.

Comment: Any comment ?...